# Magic Link login with Laravel Sanctum

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-sanctum

For my project I have a set of users that should only be able to login by requesting a Magic Link. So they  have an email address but no password. To avoid security issues, my goal was to get this working without having to save an authentication token in LocalStorage.

I've tried setting this up the following way with Laravel Sanctum:

1. When requested, I create a token for the user and email them the plaintext version.
2. The user would open the link containing the token in the querystring.
3. I would attach the (Bearer) token with the Authorization Header.
4. The next step (I assumed) would be to call a custom /api/login endpoint that uses the 'auth:sanctum' middleware. The Bearer token would authenticate the user and then I would manually login the user with `Auth::login()`. After this the active Session would be used to authenticate the user, thus avoiding having to save the token in localStorage.

But I can't call the Auth::login() method manually without getting an error `(BadMethodCallException: Method Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard::login does not exist.)`.

I can't figure out why this isn't working, or maybe I am going at this all wrong?

Comment: Auth is only available through middleware, you mentioned using auth:sanctum middleware -- it's enabled in the middleware list yes? One way of going about this is to copy the reset password process, with the exception that instead of changing a password via token, you find the user with that token, and pass their id to the Auth::loginUsingId method. There are many ways of doing this, another example would be similar to SSO where a token can verify a user. If your keen on using sanctum, go through the docs with a fine tooth comb, hope that helps!

Comment: PS are you passing the csrf_token with your fetch/axios/ajax request? Is `use Auth;` in the guard/controller class?

Comment: how you are using token in header of each request or in url paramter .?

Comment: @CodeJunkie How can I find a user by token? I only have the plaintextToken.

Comment: @CodeJunkie Yes CSRF is working fine. In fact when using the default /login endpoint with a username/password everything is working perfectly.

Comment: @KamleshPaul I'm passing the token only for the first login request. For al subsequent requests I want to use the session so I don't have to store the token in local storage.

Comment: but if you use session then `auth` middleware will work not `auth:sanctum`

Comment: `if(Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
    $userid = auth()->user()->id;
}` ... but I'm getting the point now, since Auth isn't working for you hahahaha. Does your user model have all of the necessary traits?

Comment: I think @KamleshPaul may be right. It sounds like you want to be using passport not sanctum.. no? The point of sanctum is OAuth2 with revokable long term tokens. I use the reset password concept for enrolling customers by sending an email and having them click a link where they can enter their password. I don't think theres an inherent security risk with sending the token as it appears in the database. You should create the token, then once it's used remove it from the database, if it's unused it should be removed after 24 hours. It would be impossible to guess the token before then

Comment: @generator you should put you code so i can give u better solution  login code and web.php of login

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if you sending `Sanctum` token to user via email so in 1st request you will get token from url and you can use that token to login to application  like this

```php
use Laravel\Sanctum\PersonalAccessToken;
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $personalAccessToken = PersonalAccessToken::findToken($request->token);
    $user = $personalAccessToken->tokenable;
    auth()->login($user);
    return redirect('/');
}
```

Comment: Yes ofcourse, why send it as a Bearer token when I can just send it as a parameter. Also thanks for letting me know how to find the user by token!

Comment: as per your problem i created this now you should modify as per your need thanks

Comment: Extra question =) Since I'm not using the default Laravel login endpoint. Do you have any tips of security concerns I should take care of on my own?

Comment: `auth()->login($user);` this function is used in default login internal so no difference

Comment: Quick link to check the logic in the findToken method https://github.com/laravel/sanctum/blob/2.x/src/PersonalAccessToken.php